# Using recursion to test if two strings are the same but reversed

Tags: java, string, recursion

For my assignment I have to use recursion to test if two strings are the same but reversed.

Here is the actual question:

Write a recursive method called isStringReversed which, given two String parameters, returns true if the two strings contain the same sequence of characters but in reverse order (ignoring capitalization), and false otherwise. For example, isStringReversed("piano", "oNaIp") would return true. Note: the null (empty) string and string of one letter are both the reverse of themselves.

Here's what I have made, but when I execute the program, i ***always*** get 
a false return. Heres my code:

```
public static boolean isStringReversed(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null || s1.length() == 1 || s2.length() == 1) {
        return true;
    }else if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }else {
        char s1first = Character.toLowerCase(s1.charAt(0));
        char s2last = Character.toLowerCase(s2.charAt(s2.length() - 1));

        if (s1first == s2last){
            String s1shorter = s1.substring(0, s1.length() - 1);
            String s2shorter = s2.substring(0, s2.length() - 1);
            return isStringReversed(s1shorter, s2shorter);
        }else {
            return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not link an image of your code. For many reasons, that is not helpful. Post the code here and you will be much more likely to get help.

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557))

Comment: If you used your debugger you would see that you check the first character, but then remove the last. If you have checked the first, remove the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
    String slshorter = sl.substring(0, s1.1ength() - l) ;
    String s2shorter = s2.substring(0, s2.1ength() - l) ;
```

use

```
    String slshorter = sl.substring(1) ;
    String s2shorter = s2.substring(0, s2.1ength() - 1) ;
```

Note that the second parameter of the method `substring()` means to that index **exclusive**.

Comment: Beautiful. Went through the logic in my head, and now I understand. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3):

When doing `substring` on `s1first`, you should remove the *first* character, not the last.

Just one line above that you compare *first* character of `s1first` and *last* character of `s2last`. So once you establish that they are equal, that's what you remove and continue the recursion.

Answer (score -1):

This is the recursive idea

```
        public static bool isStringReversed(string input1, string input2)
        {
            string s1 = input1.ToLower();
            string s2 = input2.ToLower();

            if(s1 == null && s2 == null) 
                return true;
            if (s1.Length == 1 && s2.Length == 1)
            {
                if (s1 == s2)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }

            if (s1.Length != s2.Length)
                return false;

            return isStringReversedRec(s1, s2, s1.Length - 1, 0);

        }

        private static bool isStringReversedRec(string s1, string s2, int indexS1, int indexS2)
        {
            if (indexS1 < 0)
                return true;

            if (s1.charAt(indexS1) != s2.charAt(indexS2))
                return false;

            return isStringReversedRec(s1, s2, indexS1 - 1, indexS2 + 1);
        }
```